# What does "of + company name + fame" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I was doing a Cambridge English Advanced Use of English Part 2 test today, when I came across the following sentence in a text:

> The first mass-produced versions, made by Sam Foster _______ Foster
>   Grant fame, were sold in the 1920s in US seaside resorts.

The task is to put one word in the gap. According to the answer key, that's **of**.
I did some research and found out it's a structure that appears with other companies as well: [Internet Explorer](https://ludwig.guru/s/of+internet+explorer+fame), [Facebook](https://ludwig.guru/s/of+facebook+fame), etc.

Is this a fancy way of saying **famous for** because I can't find any references to this structure in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fame) or [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fame)?

Comment: It's a shorter way of saying '...who is famous because of his connexion with the Foster Grant company'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have to be only a company name that provides the nature or origin of the fame. Taylor Swift of singing fame, K.C. Gillette of razor blade fame, Buzz Aldrin of Apollo moon shot fame.

> Fame noun [uncountable]
>   the state of being known about by a lot of people because of your  achievements
>   He claims he is not really interested in fame.
>
> **of ... fame
>
>   (=used to show what someone is famous
>   for)
>
>   Muhammad Ali, of boxing fame**

[Fame (Longman Dictionary)](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/fame)